# Html(forms) injection

Tags: javascript, html, post

I'm noobie in webdev, i'm trying to get some information how dangerous for server security 
coudl be such code with no data validation

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="tst">
<input type="reset" onclick="test.submit()" value="test">
</form>
```

i know we can inject html code or even js script but is it dangerous for server side ?

Comment: Any danger depends *entirely* on what you do with the data you receive. If you ignore it completely, there is no danger. If you do something with it, there might be, but it depends what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual structure of your front-end form makes no real difference to server-side security. It all depends on what the server is doing with the data once it is passed. Using Firebug,Chrome Dev tools, etc any user can write, modify, and submit forms entirely from scratch in your website. Or they can send `post/get` variables directly, without ever having seen your form... **front-end validation and structure is entirely to prompt and assist users, not to provide security to your application**. Never rely it being respected by users.

Also (aside), why not use

```
<input type="submit" value="test">
```

instead of

```
<input type="reset" onclick="test.submit()" value="test">
```

?

Comment: Only validation is that we do not interpretate php code but user can "edit" html code or add own js code

Comment: If there are no `post` handlers on the server (i.e there is no code on the server that is in charge of interpreting submitted information) then there is no real risk - with the caveat that some older versions of PHP and ASP (and possibly others) had a vulnerability where attackers could submit huge numbers (millions) of POST variables at once and the automatic process in charge of putting submitted variables into an array would lock-up... but modern defaults prevent this, and in any case the vulnerability is there with or without a form on your site.

Answer (score 1):

From here the only changeable item is the tst field.

As a general rule, any fields in the form can be changed by the client (yes, even hidden fields), so you should filter all fields (via mysqli::real_escape_string() in PHP or other methods) if they are going into the database, or if you are using this field to include() some other items on the server. You don't need to filter if you are just throwing the field against a conditional (and won't be used elsewhere), but extra security can't hurt.

As for the inject HTML/JS thing, it only applies when other scripts displays the HTML submitted. In this case, call htmlspecialchars(_uni) to make sure they don't get run.

Comment: "except submit and reset can be changed by the client" - what? Editing those is as easy as opening the console and clicking on input's `value` property. "You don't need to filter if you are just throwing the field against a conditional" REALLY? So `1 OR TRUE` `DELETE FROM TBL WHERE ID = 1 OR TRUE` (same goes for escaping quotes and such). Using prepared statements is another thing though.

Comment: From my understanding <input type="submit/reset"> are ignored by the browser. Maybe I should rephrase my response better, but who cares about these two anyways?

Comment: Not really true. When you submit through `form.submit()`, the submit button won't be serialized, but when you submit a form through a submit button that has a `name` property, its `value` will be sent to PHP as well. This is useful when you have more than one submit button in a form and used by some php frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

The user can easily edit the value of the hidden input and thus can easily do damage to your site. Depending on the function of this form, you should add slashes and htmlentities at the very least. This only matters if data is sent to the server of course.